# llamada a URL desde Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Buenos días. Siguiendo con el desarrollo de una app conectada a una placa de reles a través de la red me he encontrado con un problema.

Tengo una placa conectada en red con una ip: 192.168.0.190

para activar o desactivar los reles simplemente tengo que llamar con el navegador a http://192.168.0.190/Activo1 para activar el 1 o a http://192.168.0.190/Apago1 para apagarlo

Pues bien, lo he hecho a traves de este metodo y me gustaria que me dijeran si simplemente para hacer esa llamada(no hay que ejecutar ni procesar ningun HTML) se podria hacer de manera mas sencilla, o si esta es la correcta al menos:

```
func realizoConexion(cadena:String){


    let ip=UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "ipplaca")
    var cadenaFinal:String="http://"+ip!+cadena
      print(cadenaFinal)
    var request=NSMutableURLRequest(url:NSURL(string: cadenaFinal)! as URL)
    var session=URLSession.shared
    request.httpMethod="POST"


    var task=session.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: cadenaFinal)! as URL)


    task.resume()





}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de manera más sencilla utilizando [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#automatic-validation)

```
Alamofire.request("http://192.168.0.190/Activo1").validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("Validation Successful")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Carlos! gracias por responder...soy nuevo con swift e ios...como importo el alamofire?

Comment: Tienes que instalarlo vía Cocoapods, aquí (https://guides.cocoapods.org/) encontrarás toda la información que puedas llegar a necesitar.

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que el enfoque de tu code esta bien pero organizandolo quedaria mas limpia, algo asi:

```
let ip = "192.168.0.190"
let endpoint = "Activo1"

let stringURL = "http://\(ip)/\(endpoint)"
let url = URL(string: stringURL)!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
task.resume()
```